# ¿Como puedo ver que apks corren en una imagen docker?

Tags: docker

Intenté usando el comando

```
apk search -v
```

Lo que solo me muestra como output

```
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory
```

WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory

Como puedo hacer para que me muestre la listas de apks instaladas en ella?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando que va a listar los paquetes **instalados** en Alpine es algo como:

```
docker exec -it <el contenedor>  apk info
```

También `apk list -I`